# What's the pattern? roots and powers of n?

Tags: exponentiation

I won't hold it against anyone if this is considered a bad question but I just don't know how else to put it and really want to know.

**1st case:**
n = positive integer
a = $\sqrt n$
b = 1

**2nd case:**
n = positive integer
a = $b^2$
b = $\sqrt[3]n$
c = 1

With each new case a new variable is included which is always 1.
I'm assuming the third case must look something like this:

**3rd case:** 
n = positive integer 
a = $b^2$ 
b = $c^3$ 
c = $\sqrt[4]n$ 
d = 1

But that doesn't work as a ends up larger than n. 
All are supposed to be smaller than n and a letter which comes after another alphabetically should have a value smaller than or equal to.

There is definitely a pattern but I can't pin it down.

Comment: In the second case, it would be helpful to define $a$ as $b$ instead, and vice versa. The same applies for the 3rd case.

Comment: But then b would be bigger than a which goes against one of the rules. As they are the numbers are supposed to be in descending order and alphabetical (except for n). Both these orders matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st case is $n^1, n^{1/2}, n^0$.

The 2nd case is $n^1, n^{2/3}, n^{1/3}, n^0$.

The 3rd case should presumably be $n^1, n^{3/4}, n^{1/2}, n^{1/4}, n^0$.